# ASP.Net ajax file submit model is empty, while variables separately works ok

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, razor

I want to upload file with ajax. I have such a problem. When I am trying to receive a model - it is empty, but when I am trying to get everything as separate values - it works ok.

```
public ActionResult UploadImage(HttpPostedFileBase File, string UniqueCode)
{
   // in this case it works
}

public ActionResult UploadImage(FileUploadModel file){
  // in this case the model is empty
}
```

How the model looks

```
public class FileUploadModel {
    public string UniqueCode { get; set; }

    [ValidateImage(ErrorMessage = "Please select a PNG image smaller than 3MB")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
}
```

How do i post data. It works on input change.

```
$(document).on('change', ".preview-input", function(e){
    var blobInfo = $(this)[0].files[0];
    if (blobInfo) {
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('File', blobInfo);
        formData.append('UniqueCode',"TEST");
        $.ajax(
            {
                url: '/files/UploadAttachmentImage',
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: formData,
            })
            .success(function (response) { console.log(response); })
            .error(function (response) { console.log(response); }); 
    } else {
        console.log('321');
    }
});
```

What is the magic? How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magic of c# and .net platform. That's why I hate this language.
All I had to do is to change `FileUploadModel file` on `FileUploadModel model` and everything started to work as it should.